# Javascript String splitting and Organizing based on first letter

Tags: javascript, php, json, gateway, api-gateway

I am currently working a project that I have to use js and php to retrieve data from the gateway. Now that i have retrieved it, but the data is not organised:

```
{"timestamp":1526524809413,"data":[
{"_id":"rJeixnNtpG","data":"N11B00074","raw": 
[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,55,52],"timestamp":1525398515116}, 
{"_id":"HkzognEYpf","data":"N11E00000","raw": 
[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525398515479}, 
{"_id":"BJxXp4t6M","data":"N11A00029","raw": 
[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525398807747}
```

As you can see there are three types of data: the one starts with B(N11B00074), E(N11E00000) and A(N11A00029), followed by the 5 digits which is the data i wanted to split from the string while categorised by the type(B, E and A).

I have three tables in my web page and want to put the data into them based on the types: Like B being humidity table, A being temperature table and E being pH readings table.

[image]

So far i only managed to list them out in a table.

Is there a way that I can seperate the string and put them into an array based on their types?

Comment: I only wanted the 5-digits data and sort them into separate tables based on their types. But the table will only be showing the non-zero digits too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to group objects in an array:

```js
const input={"timestamp":1526524809413,"data":[{"_id":"rJeixnNtpG","data":"N11B00074","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,55,52],"timestamp":1525398515116},{"_id":"HkzognEYpf","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525398515479},{"_id":"BJxXp4t6M","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525398807747}]}
const arranged = input.data.reduce((accum, obj) => {
  const { data } = obj;
  const type = data[3];
  const digits = data.slice(5);
  if (!accum[type]) accum[type] = [];
  accum[type].push({ ...obj, digits });
  return accum;
}, {});
console.log(arranged);

// If you want an array and not an object:
console.log(Object.values(arranged));
```

Comment: I dont quite get this: `if (!accum[type]) accum[type] = [];
  accum[type].push({ ...obj, digits });
  return accum;` What does it do?

Comment: The accumulator is the `arranged` object as it's being constructed, passed from iteration to iteration by the reducer. If an array for the group type (for example, "B" from your "N11B00074" or "E" or "A") does not exist on the accumulator yet, it is created with those lines, and then the object is pushed to the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group the array into an object. You can use `reduce`. You can get the fourth character of the string by using `charAt`

```js
let arr = {"timestamp":1526524809413,"data":[{"_id":"rJeixnNtpG","data":"N11B00074","raw": [78,49,49,66,48,48,48,55,52],"timestamp":1525398515116}, {"_id":"HkzognEYpf","data":"N11E00000","raw": [78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525398515479}, {"_id":"BJxXp4t6M","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525398807747}]};

let result = arr.data.reduce((c, v) => {
  let l = v.data.charAt(3); //Get the 4th chatacter
  c[l] = c[l] || [];
  c[l].push(v);
  return c;
}, {});

console.log( result );
```